# Working with implicit functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Can I plot and deal with implicit functions in Mathematica?

for example :-

`x^3 + y^3 = 6xy`

Can I plot a function like this?

Comment: why did someone edit to add a "z" not at all in the original question or any of the answers?

Comment: That is not a function, it is an *equation* in the three Cartesian coordinates *x*, *y*, and *z*. The left-hand side of the equation, however, can be considered to give the 'rule' for a map (function) from \R^3 to \R. The equation then gives a particular level set of this scalar field (map, function), which is a two-dimensional surface in space.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[x^3 + y^3 == 6*x*y, {x, -2.7, 5.7}, {y, -7.5, 5}]
```

Two comments:

1. Note the double equals sign and the multiplication symbols.
2. You can find this exact input via the WolframAlpha interface.  This interface is more forgiving and accepts your input almost exactly - although, I did need to specify that I wanted some type of plot.

[image]

Comment: thank you man .. but I didn't mean only plotting .. I want to deal with it .. like differentiation and stuff .. can I differentiate this equation implicitly ?

Answer (score 18):

Yes, using `ContourPlot`.

And it's even possible to plot the text `x^3 + y^3 = 6xy` along its own curve, by replacing the `Line` primitive with several `Text` primitives:

```
ContourPlot[x^3 + y^3 == 6 x y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 Background -> Black, PlotPoints -> 7, MaxRecursion -> 1, ImageSize -> 500] /. 
{
 Line[s_] :> 
 Map[
  Text[Style["x^3+y^3 = 6xy", 16, Hue[RandomReal[]]], #, {0, 0}, {1, 1}] &, 
  s]
}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you can animate the equation along the curve, like so:

```
res = Table[ Normal[
 ContourPlot[x^3 + y^3 == 6 x y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> 600]] /. 
 {Line[s_] :> {Line[s], 
   Text[Style["x^3+y^3 = 6xy", 16, Red], s[[k]], {0, 0}, 
    s[[k + 1]] - s[[k]]]}},
  {k, 1, 448, 3}];

ListAnimate[res]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How could one not vote for this answer: how could one possibly resist the "equation train" running along the track?

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing this is what you need:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/ImplicitPlot.html

```
ContourPlot[x^3 + y^3 == 6 x*y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]